# Chart.js - Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, charts

I have the following Javascript in my `main.js` file:

```
//array object of API stuff

function createChartWinLoss(wins, losses) {

  var pieData = [
    {
      value: losses,
      color: "#F7464A",
      highlight: "#FF5A5E",
      label: "Losses"
    },
    {
      value: wins,
      color: "#46BFBD",
      highlight: "#5AD3D1",
      label: "Wins"
    }
  ];

  var pieOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke : false,
    animateScale : true
  }


  var winLossChart = document.getElementById('winLossChart').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(winLossChart).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
}

//creates the chart with test data
createChartWinLoss();

function summonerLookUp() {
  var SUMMONER_ID = "";
  var API_KEY = "keyhere";
  var sumID = $("#theKey").val();
  var div = document.getElementById('stuff');
  var combine = "";
  var array = [sumID];
  var wins;
  var losses;

  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<br />array count: " + array.length + "<br />";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    combine = "";
    SUMMONER_ID = array[i];
    getStuff(SUMMONER_ID, combine, API_KEY, div, i);
  }
}

function getStuff(SUMMONER_ID, combine, API_KEY, div, count) {
  var Topuser = SUMMONER_ID;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/' + SUMMONER_ID + '/entry?api_key=' + API_KEY,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function (json) {
      var user = Topuser;
      if (typeof json[user][0].queue != "undefined") {
        if (json[user][0].queue == "RANKED_SOLO_5x5") {
          combine = json[user][0].tier + " " + json[user][0].entries[0].division  + " - " + json[user][0].entries[0].wins + " Wins " + json[user][0].entries[0].losses + " losses";
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<br />" + count + ": " + user + " " + combine;
          var wins = json[user][0].entries[0].wins;
          var losses = json[user][0].entries[0].losses;
          //populates chart with wins losses from api
          createChartWinLoss(wins,losses);
        }
      }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      var user = Topuser;
      console.log(errorThrown);
      if (errorThrown === "Not Found") {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<br />" + count + ": " + user + " " + "UNRANKED";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Wins/Losses</h2>
  <canvas id="winLossChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

As the title suggests, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` and I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. If I had to guess I'd say it was trying to reference something that wasn't there but I'm not 100% sure on if I am correct and how to fix it. Any advice would be great.

Comment: You have a whole bunch of other stuff in this script that is unrelated to Chart.js, so it's hard for us to know where the issue is coming from. Can you reduce your problem to a smaller, self-contained example? Also, you should use the console to find more details about the error. What line is it coming from? Can you step into the problem using the debugger? (Use Pause on Exceptions in Chrome.)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see what the issue is. Added an answer.

Answer (score 16):

The line that is throwing the error is

```
var winLossChart = document.getElementById('winLossChart').getContext('2d');
```

It is saying that `document.getElementById('winLossChart')` does not exist.

This would be because your script is being interpreted before the elements have finished being created in the DOM.

You could either kick off the script in a `window.onload` function:

```
window.onload = function() {
   createChartWinLoss();
}
```

Or you could put the script tag itself as the last element in the body element of your html file.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Wins/Losses</h2>
    <canvas id="winLossChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Either solution would mean that the main entry point of your code (`createChartWinLoss`) would only happen after the other elements on the page, including the canvas, were created.

As a general process towards solving these kinds of problems, when you saw the exception in your Javascript console, you should have been able to open the stack trace, which would have led you to the fact that the error originated on the line `var winLossChart = ...`, which would have made you more likely to have been able to discover the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem. The element was being returned as dispHTMLUnkownElement.

The solution was to add `<!DOCTYPE html>`to the top of my response and then IE picked up the element type properly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help someone else...
You have to use **destroy()** method.
To made that you have to change a few things in your code:

```
var winLossChart = "";// Here you make your chart var global
function createChartWinLoss(wins, losses) {
    var pieData = [{
        value: losses,
        color: "#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Losses"
    }, {
        value: wins,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Wins"
    }];
    var pieOptions = {
        segmentShowStroke: false,
        animateScale: true
    }
    //Here´s the change inside the function where you run destroy().
    if(typeof winLossChart.destroy != "undefined") winLossChart.destroy();
    winLossChart = document.getElementById('winLossChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(winLossChart).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
}
//creates the chart with test data...
```

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3231